# Hashtable within interval

Tags: java, hashtable

Hashtable are used for mapping key to value "hash< key, value>".

I want to use a key like [a, b] instead of a special key "hash< [a, b], value>" in a way that by using c between a and b, the value be recalculated.

How can I do it?

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you are asking? With examples and expected input/output?

Comment: So, you want to use collection as a key?? Not the best choice, I'm afraid.

Comment: this isn't even a complete question

Comment: ... it's barely a complete thought

Comment: What is c? Is it the value?

Answer (score -1):

If you want range searches you need to use a NavigableMap.  You can do

```
NavigableMap<String, Value> map = ...
map.put("a", value1);
map.put("c", value2);
Value value1again = map.floorEntry("b").getValue();
Value value2again = map.ceilingEntry("b").getValue();
```

If you want to make the range the key, you can also do this with additional checking.